# How to convert empty XML node into empty string instead of SimpleXMLElement

Tags: php, simplexml

I have an XML string that sometimes has empty nodes.  When parsing this with simplexml_load_string the parser interprets any empty nodes (example `<node></node>`) to be an empty SimpleXMLElement.  I actually would prefer these come through as an empty string, or are just omitted entirely.

I've tried using LIBXML_NOBLANKS as shown below, but it seems to have no effect.  Here's some code that demonstrates the situation.  the node "p2" is empty:

```
$xml = "<xml><p1>1</p1><p2></p2><p3>3</p3></xml>";

$obj = simplexml_load_string($xml, 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOBLANKS);

header("Content-type: text/plain");

echo "STRING\n-----\n" . $xml;
echo "\n\nOBJ\n---\n" . print_r($obj,1);
echo "\n\nJSON\n----\n" . json_encode($obj);
```

Comment: I just made some tests and this does look like a bug in the XML module.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8603237/remove-empty-tags-from-a-xml-with-php

Comment: thanks for the replies.  i have a hack solution involving converting to an array which is similar to the xpath solution, but I was hoping LIBXML_NOBLANKS or some other flag would handle it without having to enumerate.

Comment: @Jason you should have posted your solution

Answer (score 0):

Here is working example for empty nodes:

```
    $nodes = $rootNode->xpath("//*[text()='']");
    foreach ($nodes as $node) {
        unset($node->{0});
    }
```

`unset($node->{0})` - is a trick which destroyes this node and removes it from parent node.