# How to remove empty nodes from XML in PHP

Tags: php, xml, nodes

I am submitting a form (after some validation) and compiling some xml like so:

```
$sxe = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);
$MyFirstNode = $sxe->addChild('MyFirstNode', $_POST["MyTitle"]); 
$MySecondNode = $sxe->addChild('MySecondNode');
$MyTHIRDNode = $MySecondNode->addChild('MyTHIRDNode', $_POST["FormElementName"]);
```

After this, I am writing the xml to a document using the following code;

```
$myFile = "myfilename.xml";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
fwrite($fh, $sxe->asXML());
fclose($fh);
```

In one scenario I need to produce the XML including any empty nodes. So in the above example, if `FormElementName` was empty it would be fine (producing something like `<MyTHIRDNode></MyTHIRDNode>`

However, in another scenario I need to remove all these empty nodes, so I am left with the ones that contain some sort of data:

```
<node>
    <one>Hello</one>
    <two></two> // <- Empty
    <three>World!</three>
</node>

// Becomes...
<node>
    <one>Hello</one>
    <three>World!</three> 
</node>
```

I have an if statement ready to differentiate between the two scenarios:

```
if ($_POST["operation"] == "UPDATE") {
    //do something
}
```

However, I am not sure how to iterate through my '$sxe' and remove these empty nodes.

Any help is much appreciated :)

Comment: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8603237/remove-empty-tags-from-a-xml-with-php

Comment: Ahh, I have tried that first answer. But could not get it to work or find any docs on how it does work

Comment: working sample: http://codepad.org/0u2B6P8g

Comment: Hmm, this may seem like an easy question, but how do I assign the result back to me $xse to be saved?

Answer (score 1):

**if(feeling lazy) do this:**

```
$xmlsz = $xml->asXML(); // Get XML code from your SXE
// Keep retrying as some empty nodes may contain other empty nodes
while(true){
    $xmlsz_ref = $xmlsz; // keep old version as reference
    // Remove <node></node> empty nodes
    $xmlsz = preg_replace('~<[^\\s>]+>\\s*</\\1>~si', null, $xmlsz);
    // Remove <node /> empty nodes
    $xmlsz = preg_replace('~<[^\\s>]+\\s*/>~si', null, $xmlsz);
    if($xmlsz_ref === $xmlsz) break; // If not changed, break!
}
$xmlsz = simplexml_load_string($xmlsz); // reparse XML code to your SEX
```

*Code was written here and not tested.* Should work!