# Remove empty XML tags with PHP but ignore tags with attributes

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I know its possible to remove empty XML tags using XPath (as seen here - [Remove empty tags from a XML with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8603237/remove-empty-tags-from-a-xml-with-php))

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

foreach( $xpath->query('//*[not(node())]') as $node ) {
    $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
}

$doc->formatOutput = true;
echo $doc->savexml();
```

but is it possible to use a similar method to still remove empty tags but keep ones that have attributes?

e.g.

```
<range starts_at="2012-11-22" ends_at="2012-11-26"></range>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with this XPath

```
'//*[not(node()) and not(@*)]'
```

Comment: Do you know how include nodes with just void attributes too ?