# Remove self-closing tags in XPath

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I have used this solution to remove empty tags from my generated XML.

[Remove empty tags from a XML with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8603237/remove-empty-tags-from-a-xml-with-php)

However, if the generated XML has nested nodes that are empty, for example:

```
<metro>
   <distance></distance>
   <name></name>
</metro>
```

Then the result for that portion will be

```
<metro/>
```

Is there a way to remove those self-closing tags?

Comment: What is the requested output? Should the whole node be deleted in case it's empty (so you get nothing back in case distance and name have no value at all)?

Comment: @matthias_h correct. If such a case occurs, instead of <metro/> I should get nothing.

Comment: And you process the xml with php or would an xpath help you?

Comment: @matthias_h I use Xpath with PHP, like in th question I referenced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple modification to the XPath you referenced should accomplish what you need:

```
//*[not(normalize-space())]

foreach( $xpath->query('//*[not(normalize-space())]') as $node ) {
    $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
}
```

The answer in the question you linked to can be interpreted as "Match all elements that do not have a child node". `metro` has five child nodes, so that XPath does not match it.

The XPath in my answer can be interpreted as "Match all elements that do not contain any non-whitespace text."

I suggest you read up on [`normalize-space()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-normalize-space) if you are unfamiliar with it, but basically in this case, it produces an empty string if all the text nodes within an element are whitespace, so in the case of `metro` we have:

```
not(normalize-space())

not(normalize-space(.))  // If no argument is specified, the context node is used.

not(normalize-space("    // normalize-space() expects a string, so the nodeset . is 
                         // replaced with its string-value (all the text it contains).


"))

not("")                  // normalize-space() eliminates all leading and trailing
                         // whitespace.

not(false())             // not() expects a boolean, and the boolean equivalent of
                         // the empty string is false()

true()
```

Since the predicate evaluates to `true()`, `metro` is selected.

Comment: @Alexey Added an explanation above.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if you can use it in your setup but with the XPath-Expression

```
/*/metro/*[normalize-space()]/parent::*
```

you would only get metro-nodes with children that are not empty.

Comment: Metro is not the only tag that can have this situation. It has to be a more global solution.

Comment: But the suggestion in the answer could at least work for metro and would "just" have to be adjusted to work for some more tags..? Difficult to guess without knowing the XML.