# Remove all empty html elements using PHP: DOMDocument

Tags: php, domdocument

Is there any way to remove all empty elements from an html without using regex?

I did this with `DOMXPath`

```
$this->dom->loadHTML($document, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
$xpath = new \DOMXPath($this->dom);
while (($node_list = $xpath->query('//*[not(*) and not(@*) and not(text()[normalize-space()])]')) && $node_list->length) {
    foreach ($node_list as $node) {
        $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should be able to use domdocument as you tagged. Do you have some code you are having issues with?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8603283/7028432

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove empty tags from a XML with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8603237/remove-empty-tags-from-a-xml-with-php)

Answer (score 1):

Since it may be quite unclear, that the question has been already answered by the author (through editing the post) and I can't comment to ask for appropriate question closure, copying the same code as an actual answer.
An important thing: comments refer to another topic, but the solution there works **only** for flat documents, while the solution from OP does work with deep trees. It helped me quite a bunch.

```php
$this->dom->loadHTML($document, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
$xpath = new \DOMXPath($this->dom);
while (($node_list = $xpath->query('//*[not(*) and not(@*) and not(text()[normalize-space()])]')) && $node_list->length) {
    foreach ($node_list as $node) {
        $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
    }
}
```