# Xpath to remove empty nodes within XML with child nodes

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I am using the following code in which I pass the dom and this returns the XML without the empty nodes

```
/**
 * Remove Empty Tags
 *
 * @return void
 * @author Fahad Sheikh
 **/
public function remove_empty_tags($dom)
{
    // Remove Empty Tags
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);


    foreach( $xpath->query('//*[not(node())]') as $node ) {
        $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
    }
}
```

But this returns the following XML where it for some reason combines the nested XML tag values and deletes their tag.

```
<formxml>
<type>Potential customer</type>
<origin>Content</origin>
<source>test source<medium>test medium</medium>
<campaign>test campaign</campaign>
<matchtype>terms</matchtype>
<test>valueonevaluetwo</test>
<keyword>test term</keyword>
<ad>test</ad>
</formxml>
```

Instead, this should be:

```
<formxml>
<type>Potential customer</type>
<origin>Content</origin>
<source>test source<medium>test medium</medium>
<campaign>test campaign</campaign>
<matchtype>terms</matchtype>
<test>
    <testvarone>valueone</testvarone>
    <testvartwo>valuetwo</testvartwo>
</test>
<keyword>test term</keyword>
<ad>test</ad>
</formxml>
```

This solution was mentioned here:

[Remove empty tags from a XML with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8603237/remove-empty-tags-from-a-xml-with-php)

Comment: What is your original XML ? Also it's maybe a typo but `<source>` is missing an end tag `</source>`.

Comment: Yea that is a type.

Comment: Original XML only has a couple of more xml tags

Comment: Probably a full code needed, because I can't reproduce this behavior... For me it works as you mentioned/you want... and maybe  source xml too.

Comment: The problem was within an another function this was working okay you were right thanks.