preg_replace help to remove empty "li" element
Hi I need a script to remove, from a html string, all "li" elements empty or with only spaces. But also with inside empty tag (one or nested empty tags)
I use this preg_replace to remove succesfully only empty "li". In this case the 4th li.
But i don't know how to remove last "li" that has got an empty "span" inside it... any suggest? Thanks
$contenuto = '<ol style="margin-top: 0cm; margin-bottom: 0cm;">
<li style="margin: 0cm 0cm 0cm 47.6px; text-align: justify; line-height: normal; font-size: 11pt; font-family: Calibri, sans-serif; text-indent: 0.4px;"><span style="font-size: 10.0pt;">x</span></li>
<li style="margin: 0cm 0cm 0cm 47.6px; text-align: justify; line-height: normal; font-size: 11pt; font-family: Calibri, sans-serif; text-indent: 0.4px;"><span style="font-size: 10.0pt;">y</span></li>
<li style="margin: 0cm 0cm 0cm 47.6px; text-align: justify; line-height: normal; font-size: 11pt; font-family: Calibri, sans-serif; text-indent: 0.4px;"><span style="font-size: 10.0pt;">z</span></li>
<li style="margin: 0cm 0cm 0cm 47.6px; text-align: justify; line-height: normal; font-size: 11pt; font-family: Calibri, sans-serif; text-indent: 0.4px;"></li>
<li style="margin: 0cm 0cm 0cm 47.6px; text-align: justify; line-height: normal; font-size: 11pt; font-family: Calibri, sans-serif; text-indent: 0.4px;"><span style="font-size: 10.0pt; color: red;"> </span></li>
</ol>';

$contenuto = preg_replace('/<li[^>]*>(\s|&nbsp;)*<\/li>/', '', $contenuto);

echo $contenuto;


Please carefully read this finely crafted essay: You can't parse HTML with regex.

Maybe this page can be helpful using DOMDocument / xpath https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8603237/remove-empty-tags-from-a-xml-with-php

Or extend your current regex:  <li[^>]*>(?:\s+|&nbsp;|</?span[^>]*>)*<\/li>

@KIKOSoftware Please stop linking to the "Zalgo" / anti-Cthulhu regex rant, Using regular expressions to parse HTML: why not?, Why you shouldn't and when you should use regular expressions?

@bobblebubble You've got a point. Luckily there are other answers on that page, and other comments here. The point remains: RegEx is poor at parsing HTML that is changeable, and this question seems to imply it is. If it wasn't you wouldn't need the RegEx.

Re-reading your question I think @CasimiretHippolyte's regex does very well for this and it's constructed in such a nice way you could only target li-tags by adding a lookahead at start: <(?=li\b). What I forgot was that you also have &nbsp; so you need to add that too after the \s* attach (?:&nbsp;\s*)* ending up with this adjustment of Casimir's pattern (regex101).

PHP DOM removing empty elements as well as others and Remove all empty html elements using PHP: DOMDocument and Remove empty tags from a XML with PHP and Removing elements with no children DOM PHP

The XPath to select the empty li nodes is
//li[not(normalize-space())]

An XPath query is not what you asked for. But I find that much more concise and readable and easier to come up with than a reliable Regex that does the same.
Unfortunately, PHP doesn't have something like an xpath_replace function which hides away all the boilerplate to do what preg_replace does for a Regex. So you'd have to write some additional code to get your desired output:
<?php
$html = '<ol style="margin-top: 0cm; margin-bottom: 0cm;">
<li style="margin: 0cm 0cm 0cm 47.6px; text-align: justify; line-height: normal; font-size: 11pt; font-family: Calibri, sans-serif; text-indent: 0.4px;"><span style="font-size: 10.0pt;">x</span></li>
<li style="margin: 0cm 0cm 0cm 47.6px; text-align: justify; line-height: normal; font-size: 11pt; font-family: Calibri, sans-serif; text-indent: 0.4px;"><span style="font-size: 10.0pt;">y</span></li>
<li style="margin: 0cm 0cm 0cm 47.6px; text-align: justify; line-height: normal; font-size: 11pt; font-family: Calibri, sans-serif; text-indent: 0.4px;"><span style="font-size: 10.0pt;">z</span></li>
<li style="margin: 0cm 0cm 0cm 47.6px; text-align: justify; line-height: normal; font-size: 11pt; font-family: Calibri, sans-serif; text-indent: 0.4px;"></li>
<li style="margin: 0cm 0cm 0cm 47.6px; text-align: justify; line-height: normal; font-size: 11pt; font-family: Calibri, sans-serif; text-indent: 0.4px;"><span style="font-size: 10.0pt; color: red;"> </span></li>
</ol>';

$emptyLists = '//li[not(normalize-space())]';

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
foreach($xpath->query($emptyLists) as $node) {
    $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
}

echo $dom->saveHTML();

will output
<ol style="margin-top: 0cm; margin-bottom: 0cm;">
<li style="margin: 0cm 0cm 0cm 47.6px; text-align: justify; line-height: normal; font-size: 11pt; font-family: Calibri, sans-serif; text-indent: 0.4px;"><span style="font-size: 10.0pt;">x</span></li>
<li style="margin: 0cm 0cm 0cm 47.6px; text-align: justify; line-height: normal; font-size: 11pt; font-family: Calibri, sans-serif; text-indent: 0.4px;"><span style="font-size: 10.0pt;">y</span></li>
<li style="margin: 0cm 0cm 0cm 47.6px; text-align: justify; line-height: normal; font-size: 11pt; font-family: Calibri, sans-serif; text-indent: 0.4px;"><span style="font-size: 10.0pt;">z</span></li>


</ol>

Demo https://3v4l.org/o0K0H

Thankyou, it works great. I've modified this line to prevent adding  tag not needed: $dom->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);

I don't think saveHTML() needs any parameters passed in. https://3v4l.org/o0K0H

@mickmackusa you can pass a DOMNode to saveHTML. Then it will just use that tree.

But yes, you don't need it when using LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD

I answer to quote 2 things:

@bobble bubble is right when he said you can parse small pieces of HTML
using Regex, especially when you are sure about the encoding /
language...
You can use ChatGPT when you deal with Regex, it works well when you
need something simple.

Here is my answer:
$regex = '/<li[^>]*>(?:\s*|(?:<[^>\/]+[^>]*>\s*<\/[^>]+>)(?:\s*|<\/?\w+[^>]*>\s*))<\/li>/s';
$contenuto = preg_replace($regex, '', $contenuto);    


Your RegEx doesn't work when I change the <span> to a <b>: https://3v4l.org/EGb2j You may argue that that's not what's asked, but I think it is. The question talks about "empy tags" and gives <span> just as an example.

@KIKOSoftware indeed ! I misread the question sorry, updated, it seems to work with any empty tag now

Yes, you can adapt your RegEx as long as you know what to adapt to. The problem with HTML is that it can vary a lot. Suppose the <b> tag surrounds the <span> tag, then your expression fails again: https://3v4l.org/0Gmf3 This can go on endlessly. Your expression will become so complicated that no sane person can understand it anymore. Try the other answer here, note how it can cope with any HTML and is still, somewhat, comprehensible.
